# Showing information when button is clicked on

Tags: javascript

I need help with the following. I need the information to be displayed when I click the button, it is currently doing so through classes. How can I make the function run when the button is clicked?

```
 function mostrarProvincia(provincia) {

            console.log(provincia.value);
            if (provincia.value == 1) {
                document.getElementById('lima').classList.remove('d-none');
            } else {
                document.getElementByid('lima').classList.add('d-none');
            };};
```

```
.d-none {
            display: none;
        }
```

```
<div class="alinear_dropdown">

        <select id="provincia" onchange="mostrarProvincia(this)">
            <option value="0 selected"> Selecciona tu Provincia ...</option>
            <option value="1">LIMA</option>
        </select>
        
        <button style="padding: 20px 32px;
    width: 18rem;background-color:#DC241F;color: #FFFFFF;">BUSCAR</button>

        <div id="lima" class="d-none">
            <div style="background-color:#F1F1F1;    border-radius: 1rem;">
                <h3 style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 20px;">Automotores Yoshival Huaraz</h3>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/hFrzeSaDVmXfNQiv8">
                    <p style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">Av. Monterrey S/N (Carretera Huaraz Monterrey). </p>
                </a>
                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
                    <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
                    <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
                    <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
                    <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i need help with this code

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onchange` from the `<select>` field, and reference the `<select>` field through a variable in the function. Add the function as the `onclick` handler for your button.

```js
function mostrarProvincia() {

  const provincia = document.getElementById('provincia');
  if (provincia.value == 1) {
    document.getElementById('lima').classList.remove('d-none');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('lima').classList.add('d-none');
  };
};
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="alinear_dropdown">

  <select id="provincia">
    <option value="0 selected"> Selecciona tu Provincia ...</option>
    <option value="1">LIMA</option>
  </select>

  <button style="padding: 20px 32px;
    width: 18rem;background-color:#DC241F;color: #FFFFFF;" onclick="mostrarProvincia()">BUSCAR</button>

  <div id="lima" class="d-none">
    <div style="background-color:#F1F1F1;    border-radius: 1rem;">
      <h3 style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 20px;">Automotores Yoshival Huaraz</h3>
      <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/hFrzeSaDVmXfNQiv8">
        <p style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">Av. Monterrey S/N (Carretera Huaraz Monterrey). </p>
      </a>
      <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
        <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
        <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
        <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
        <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the onchange attribute from select.

change js code with below js code.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector("select");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click",mostrarProvincia)
function mostrarProvincia() {

            console.log(selectElement.value);
            if (selectElement.value == 1) {
                document.getElementById('lima').classList.remove('d-none');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('lima').classList.add('d-none');
            };};
```

```css
.d-none {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="alinear_dropdown">

        <select id="provincia">
            <option value="0 selected"> Selecciona tu Provincia ...</option>
            <option value="1">LIMA</option>
        </select>
        
        <button style="padding: 20px 32px;
    width: 18rem;background-color:#DC241F;color: #FFFFFF;">BUSCAR</button>

        <div id="lima" class="d-none">
            <div style="background-color:#F1F1F1;    border-radius: 1rem;">
                <h3 style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 20px;">Automotores Yoshival Huaraz</h3>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/hFrzeSaDVmXfNQiv8">
                    <p style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">Av. Monterrey S/N (Carretera Huaraz Monterrey). </p>
                </a>
                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
                    <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
                    <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;">
                    <p>+56 9 9711 8500</p>
                    <a href="tel:+56 9 9711 8500" style="padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;color:#DC241F;font-weight: 900;">Llamar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

one more mistake you wrote wrong spelling of getelementbyid in the else part of the if else